# Allocating Permissions for Users with Negative Reputation

Tags: forum, users, permissions, reputation

A friend and myself are currently working on permissions for users with a negative reputation on our forum. If a specific user has a negative reputation, what are the drawbacks of not allowing him/her to GIVE negative reputation to another user? We are only familiar with one MyBB forum that DOES allow users with a NEGATIVE reputation to GIVE negative reputation to others. Why do they feel this is an intelligent design decision?

Comment: Questions about the design of third-party software would primarily result in opinion-based answers, so are considered off-topic for this site. You might be able to ask this on the [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions) Stack Exchange site however.

Comment: Ah, thank you, Dan! I was having a small dilemma finding the proper place to put a question like this. Appreciate the response!

Comment: No problem, good luck. Feel free to ask other [webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) related questions here in the future.